# Relación Hibernate @OneToMany en la misma entidad

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Mi problema es que quiero relacionar una tabla con sigo misma, la relación que quiero es **OneToMany**, he tratado de solo poner la notación de hibernate pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.poc.entity.Tabla1.tabla1

Esta es mi clase:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer es la forma en que lo estoy haciendo, puesto que si comento la relación con sigo misma, se crean las tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La relación OneToMany es uno a muchos, por lo tanto, se espera que definas un campo collection.

```
// En la tabla debe existir un columna N_MISMA_RELACION y N_ID debe ser la primary key
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="N_MISMA_RELACION", referencedColumnName="N_ID")
private Set<Table1> tables;
```

Esta relación es imposible porque significa que tienes un N_MISMA_RELACION que apunta a varios  N_ID's. Supuestamente N_MISMA_RELACION tambien es una Primary Key y tendrías claves duplicadas en esta relación.A menos que sea un tipo de tabla de tablas pero en ese caso existen otros formas de declaración.

Lo lógico es que seamuchow  a Uno

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="N_MISMA_RELACION", referencedColumnName="N_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Table1 table1;
```

Y si quieres la inverda:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy=table1)
 private set<Table1> tables;
```

Relaciones medias raras pero pruebalas